# Insert blob data into oracle database with pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, blob

I have created the following table in an oracle database, which I insert, update and read using pl sql functions.

In particular, I am having problems inserting attachment data, that is, with the blob type data. This data can be an image or a pdf file.

This is the table:

```
  CREATE TABLE "CID"."NOTIFICATIONS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AGE_FROM" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "AGE_TO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "LOCALITY_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "MESSAGE_TITLE" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MESSAGE_BODY" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "ATTACHMENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DEFAULT 'none' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ATTACHMENT" BLOB, 
    "CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "UPDATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "DELETED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
     CHECK (attachment_type in ('none', 'img', 'pdf')) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "NOTIFICATIONS_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA"  ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA" 
 LOB ("ATTACHMENT") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "DATA" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ;
```

And this is the pl sql function to insert data into the same table

```
FUNCTION INSERT_ROW (p_table_name IN VARCHAR2, p_columns IN VARCHAR2, p_values IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || p_table_name || ' (' || p_columns || ') VALUES (' || p_values || ')';
  RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
END;

END CIUD_UTILIDADES_PKG;
```

this are the columns names to insert the data:

```
AGE_FROM, AGE_TO, DEPARTMENT_ID, LOCALITY_ID, MESSAGE_TITLE, MESSAGE_BODY, ATTACHMENT_TYPE,ATTACHMENT,CREATED_AT
```

And this are the data:

```
3,40,0,0,'First notification','First body notification','img','data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQYAAABbCAIAAAAeMLz2AAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAAEHRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBTaHV0dGVyY4LQCQAAIABJREFUeNrsvWmvZNeVJbbWPufeiDfP+d7LOTkkZ1ISRVKiKFEiRQ01tmpA2d3lRrtsA22g/cGGAX+w/......, ,sysdate
```

**Am I inserting the attachment field wrong? in this case it is a base64 but is it inserted in the same way as the other fields?**

To insert data in Laravel what I do is the following:

```
public function insertRow(string $table_name, string $columns, string $values): bool{

    $res = DB::statement("DECLARE l_result BOOLEAN; BEGIN l_result := CID_UTIL_PKG.INSERT_ROW(:table_name, :columns, :values); END;",
        [
            'table_name' => $table_name,
            'columns' => $columns,
            'values' => $values,
        ]);
    
    return $res;

}
```

Comment: I've never worked with binary data like this in Oracle, but my initial thought would be you would need to convert base64 into actual raw (check out the utl_encode package), and then you can append it to a blob (insert into table values (empty_bob()) returning blobcol into var_blob... then use dbms_lob to append to the var_blob variable.

Comment: this explains it very good https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/how-to-insert-a-pdf-or-jpeg-image-into-a-blob-column-of-a-t-0996

Comment: @nbk, that forum discussion seems to be about loading from files (bfile), OP is passing in base64 values into the procedure, so there'd be no files involved.

Comment: @PaulW this is another approach better described in that thread than anything that i could find here, if he doesn't like it he can ignore it.

Comment: The drawback is that the database is not on the server where I have the images and I have to define a pl sql function. That is, I have to send the image from a server to the DB. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

*quote: "That is, I have to send the image from a server to the DB. How could I do that?"*

You should read the file into BLOB. To do it you need [Directory object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23//adlob/directory-objects.html#GUID-F7440C27-C7F0-4874-8C3C-F3BC1534CBE0) defining the folder where the file is stored.
Below is the code to read the file into BLOB. Parametrs are the name of Directory object and the name of the file. Returned BLOB can be inserted into a BLOB column in your table.

```sql
FUNCTION FILE2BLOB  (mDir       IN  VARCHAR2,
                     mFileName  IN  VARCHAR2) RETURN BLOB
IS
BEGIN
    Declare 
        mBLOB       BLOB := Empty_Blob();
        mBinFile    BFILE := BFILENAME(mDir, mFileName);
    Begin
        DBMS_LOB.OPEN(mBinFile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);             -- Open BFILE  
        DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary(mBLOB, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.Session);    -- Initialyze BLOB locator
        DBMS_LOB.OPEN(mBLOB, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);               -- Open BLOB locator for writing
        DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile(mBLOB, mBinFile, DBMS_LOB.getLength(mBinFile));   -- Read BFILE into BLOB
        DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(mBLOB);              -- Close BLOB locator
        DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(mBinFile);           -- Close BFILE 
        RETURN mBLOB;       -- Return BLOB
    End;
END FILE2BLOB;
```

Insert:

```sql
Insert Into YOUR_TABLE_NAME ( COL_1, COL_2, COL_BLOB )
Values( val_for_col_1, val_for_col_2, FILE2BLOB(your_DirectoryObject, yourFile) )
```